# How to add element to a sequence in opencv 2.3 coding in c

Tags: c++, c, opencv

I have created a sequence by cvCreateSequence now I want to add an element(a CvPoint) to tthis seq,how can I do this. I found this macro CV_SEQUENCE_FIELDS,is this helpful if yes than how?I am not getting this..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use cvSeqPush() :

```
 char* cvSeqPush(
CvSeq* seq,
void* element = NULL
);
```

In your case the element will be a CvPoint.
You can get more info [here](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/core/doc/dynamic_structures.html?highlight=cvseqpush#char%2a%20cvSeqPush%28CvSeq%2a%20seq,%20void%2a%20element%29)